# SSRS: Dropdown is not populated in filter in Report Builder

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Whenever I try to apply filter to an attribute, which has ValueSelection= Dropdown, the dropdown is not populated and error message "The requested list could not be retrieved because the query is not valid or a connection could not be made to the data source" is shown instead.

If I set up ValueSelection=List I am getting a different error message:

An attempt has been made to use a semantic query extension associated with the data extension 'SQL' that is not registered for this report server. 
(Microsoft.ReportingServices.SemanticQueryEngine)

This happens within BIDS environment and was observed both in SQL 2005 and SQL 2008.

I've already studied articles, which discussed the similiar problem, but neither of them applied to my case. The user account in data source has all necessary rights, data could be retrieved without any problem (for example if i try "Explore data" in data source view). The SQL profiler shows that no query is being sent to SQL Server when there is an attempt to populate dropdown. So nothing is wrong with the query, it is simply never executed.

Comment: Are you trying to populate the values for a parameter from a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is not working. Try to test you connection by trying a simple table and query output.

This will enable you to test the connection before trying anything advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem and in my case it was caused by wrong connection string in Data Source - instead of just having a SQL Server name like "SOMESQLSERVER_MACHINE" I had for some reason "SOMESQLSERVER_MACHINE.our.corp.domain". It had to be the same, but then I realized that the domain is wrong, after removing it all works like a charm again. That said: it's always good idea to start with detailed checks on your basic settings.
Otherwise this could be a problem with permissions to the folders on Report Manager.